# Size depth tradeoffs for monotone arithmetic circuits

Tags: arithmetic-circuits

Are there any size depth trade-offs known for monotone arithmetic circuits that compute permanent and determinant?

Comment: there are no monotone circuits that compute the determinant because the determinant is not a monotone function.

Comment: I meant sum of monotone ( I am unsure if there is a separate name for it). May be something like this http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019097000690